# java Runtime exec failed

Tags: java

I created FileTest.java and RuntimeTest.java in the same package named test. Then, in RuntimeTest.java , I used Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java test.FileTest") to run FileTest.java, but it seems that the FileTest.java didn't run. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: You can't run .java files. You can only execute .class or .jar extensions

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Java is not interpreted runtime. You should use something else.